# INVALID is not a valid start token

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, prometheus

I have my microservice (springboot+actuator in Kubernetes) exposing `/metrics` endpoint.

From a pod I can retrieve metrics by using a simple `curl svc:8080/metrics`

But in Prometheus target I get this error: `INVALID is not a valid start token`

[image]

My `prometheus.yml` is the following:

```
   global:
      scrape_interval: 60s
      scrape_timeout: 10s
      evaluation_interval: 10s

    alerting:
      alertmanagers:
      - static_configs:
        - targets:
          - alertmanager:9093

    rule_files:
      - "/etc/prometheus-rules/usage.rules"
      - "/etc/prometheus-rules/availability.rules"

    scrape_configs:
      - job_name: 'prometheus'
        static_configs:
          - targets: 
            - prometheus:9090    

      - job_name: 'kubernetes-apiservers'
        kubernetes_sd_configs:
        - role: endpoints
        scheme: https
        tls_config:
          ca_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt
        bearer_token_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token
        relabel_configs:
        - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_namespace, __meta_kubernetes_service_name, __meta_kubernetes_endpoint_port_name]
          action: keep
          regex: default;kubernetes;https

     - job_name: 'kubernetes-nodes'
        kubernetes_sd_configs:
        - role: node
        relabel_configs:
        - action: labelmap
          regex: __meta_kubernetes_node_label_(.+)
        - source_labels: [__address__]
          regex: '(.*):10250'
          replacement: '${1}:10255'
          target_label: __address__

      - job_name: 'kubernetes-endpoints'
        kubernetes_sd_configs:
        - role: endpoints
        relabel_configs:
        - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_service_annotation_prometheus_io_scrape]
          action: keep
          regex: true
        - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_service_annotation_prometheus_io_scheme]
          action: replace
          target_label: __scheme__
          regex: (https?)
        - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_service_annotation_prometheus_io_path]
          action: replace
          target_label: __metrics_path__
          regex: (.+)
        - source_labels: [__address__, __meta_kubernetes_service_annotation_prometheus_io_port]
          action: replace
          target_label: __address__
          regex: ([^:]+)(?::\d+)?;(\d+)
          replacement: $1:$2
        - action: labelmap
          regex: __meta_kubernetes_service_label_(.+)
        - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_namespace]
          action: replace
          target_label: kubernetes_namespace
        - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_service_name]
          action: replace
          target_label: kubernetes_name    

      - job_name: 'kubernetes-pods'
        kubernetes_sd_configs:
        - role: pod
        relabel_configs:
        - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_scrape]
          action: keep
          regex: true
        - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_path]
          action: replace
          target_label: __metrics_path__
          regex: (.+)
        - source_labels: [__address__, __meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_port]
          action: replace
          regex: ([^:]+)(?::\d+)?;(\d+)
          replacement: ${1}:${2}
          target_label: __address__
        - action: labelmap
          regex: __meta_kubernetes_pod_label_(.+)
        - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_namespace]
          action: replace
          target_label: kubernetes_namespace
        - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_name]
          action: replace
          target_label: kubernetes_pod_name
        - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_container_port_number]
          action: keep
          regex: 9\d{3}

      - job_name: 'kubernetes-services'
        kubernetes_sd_configs:
        - role: service
        metrics_path: /health
        params:
          module: [http_2xx]
        relabel_configs:
        - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_service_annotation_prometheus_io_probe]
          action: keep
          regex: true
        - source_labels: [__address__]
          target_label: __param_target
        - target_label: __address__
          replacement: blackbox
        - source_labels: [__param_target]
          target_label: instance
        - action: labelmap
          regex: __meta_kubernetes_service_label_(.+)
        - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_namespace]
          target_label: kubernetes_namespace
        - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_service_name]
          target_label: kubernetes_name
```

Any suggestions, please?

Comment: Can you post your Prometheus configs?

Comment: I added prometheus.yml

Answer (score 3):

Sure, you can manually reach `<svc>:<port>/metrics`, but you never told Prometheus to scrape it ;-)

See an example here, take a close look at lines #86 & #129:
https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/blob/master/documentation/examples/prometheus-kubernetes.yml

If you run into other issues with Prometheus, or to quickly solve your current one, try questioning the method you used to set up Prometheus on Kubernetes to begin with (because your YAML is probably only one symptom), and re-install from the Helm chart:
https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/prometheus