# How to fix ' \"INVALID\" is not a valid start token" ' in Prometheus

Tags: prometheus

I have spring-boot project with dependencies for web and actuator which is running on port 7071

I am able to see prometheus and metric for my service triggers
http://localhost:7071/prometheus
http://localhost:7071/metrics

but somehow http://localhost:9090/targets appearing DOWN with error "INVALID" is not a valid start token

I have tried to checked similar issue but did not help - [INVALID is not a valid start token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52519541/invalid-is-not-a-valid-start-token)

prometheus.yml

```
scrape_configs:
  # The job name is added as a label `job=<job_name>` to any timeseries scraped from this config.
  - job_name: 'prometheus'

    # metrics_path defaults to '/metrics'
    # scheme defaults to 'http'.

    static_configs:
    - targets: ['localhost:9090','localhost:7071']
```

can you please help what is wrong with yaml configurations ?

Comment: I have opened promtool.exe to see the logs, below what if found


` level=warn ts=2019-04-28T15:26:39.700Z caller=scrape.go:937 component="scrape manager" scrape_pool=monitorrestapi target=http://localhost:7071/metrics msg="append failed" err="\"INVALID\" is not a valid start token" `

Comment: Do you have valid metric pages when you GET http://localhost:9090/metrics and http://localhost:7071/metrics ? Try it with curl.

Comment: Yes I am able launch C:\Users\praveena>start "http://localhost:7071/metrics" and C:\Users\praveena>start "http://localhost:9090/metrics"  in my command prompt.

Comment: did you find a solution for it?

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution after 1 week of searching on internet, that When you are inside a container, you cannot access the localhost directly. You will need to add docker.for.win.localhost to your prometheus.yml file. See below:

```
 - job_name: 'spring-actuator'
metrics_path: '/actuator/prometheus'
scrape_interval: 5s
static_configs:
  - targets: ['docker.for.win.localhost:8080']
```